# Azure architecture question

Tags: architecture, azure

Please tell me if my reasoning below is valid.

As I understand it, when you build an Azure application you build it from bottom up with the cloud in mind (for example, resources like databases are handled diffrently in an Azure application than in your old standard application).

This means you cannot start to build your business critical Azure application and then in the end decide to host it in the old fashioned way for some reason (maybe you're not happy with performance or whatever).

Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 5):

To some extent the reasoning is correct- certain cloud resources, like Azure Table storage, don't have a feature-for-feature counterpart in the non-hosted world.

That said, most of what Azure does for you can be replicated with a combination of databases, queues (like MSMQ or Tibco), network filesystems, etc.  NoSQL databases like [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) provide the scalability of a hosted cloud on your own infrastructure, but they will require revisiting some of the assumptions that you have made about data access.  Microsoft also markets an [appliance for a private cloud](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud/cloudpowersolutions/private_cloud.aspx) which replicates the Azure environment locally.

In the end, the amount of effort involved in moving between the cloud and a non-hosted environment comes down to how well your code is factored, particularly in the areas of data access and interprocess communication.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  As a particular example, if your app is just ASP.NET with SQL Azure, running it on a standard IIS box with SQL Server is trivial.

Comment: +1 Expanding on the idea, if you architect your application in a way where all your "infrastructure" calls (queue, data, file) are done in a service-oriented way, you will have constructed a solution that isn't bound to one infrastructure.  You could then, with trivial effort, move to Azure, EC2, rackspace, an onsite private cloud, a virtualized "traditional" datacenter, etc.  In the end, designing in the "cloud way" even if you have no intent of going to a cloud at this point is one of the best future-proofing decisions you can make.

Comment: minor correction, the private cloud link you provide is really for MSFT's HyperV environment. Their local version of Azure, the Azure Appliance, is in the works but don't confuse it with the hyperV stuff.

Comment: +1 totally agree. that doesn't apply just to Azure, but to every piece of software and technology.

Answer (score 1):

If you **design your business system with the decoupling and domain-driven-design in mind**, then it will be easy to migrate to the cloud (Azure, Amazon etc), scale, distribute or do whatever is needed.

Just a few things to keep in mind:

- Messaging
- Domain-Driven Design
- Principles of [CQRS Architectures](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but still... if you for example write an Azure application for a customer and deploy it to the cloud: -What if the customer later decides they want to host it for them selves? (Could be a number of reasons: performance, security, non-strategic vendor lock-in, cost, etc) In this case you will have to involve developers again, test it again, etc (it may or may not be the same people). You cannot swap to traditional hosting by simply changing one line of some configuration parameter, etc (unless, of course, you acctually built it "for dual platforms" from the beginning, tested it for both platforms, etc.

I think Azure, as a hosting option, feels pretty intrusive on application design.

What about that Web Role/Worker Role-stuff? Is that something that lock you further in on Azure? Is it something that easily can be moved to traditional ASP .NET web application / Windows Service?

Sorry for being such dull sceptic! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approachs to this:

1. You can move the application in house, without making any changes by running on Azure Appliance. http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appliance/
2. You can architect the solution so that you do not use functionality that is specific to Azure. For example store data in Azure SQL not in Azure Table Storage. A web frontend built in ASP.Net MVC will run in Azure and on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when it comes IaaS (OS , Hosting Environment) ,migrate to OnPremise may not be tough. But in case we are heavily using  different services, cloud vendor provides as part of PaaS , then we will have to face that burden  during migration.